# pdf won't convert using ghostscript unless i've saved it in acrobat using 'Optimized PDF'

Tags: optimization, pdf, ghostscript

We have ghostscript setup on our server to convert a PDF into separate TIFF images when it is uploaded. It's works perfectly most of the time, however sometimes it fails. I have managed to solve this on a per PDF basis by opening the problem PDF and saving it in Acrobat as an 'Optimized PDF' and specifically with JUST these two attributes checked:
'Discard unreferenced named destinations' (in Clean Up)
'Optimize page content' (in Clean Up)
(nothing else has been checked in any section, just these two)
**My question is, is there a way to have ghostscript do what I am having to currently do?**
The reason I need ghostscript to do this is because it has to be fully automated so users can upload a pdf and it gets converted into images.
If it helps, here are the ghostscript settings we are using:
 
-dQUIET
-dSAFER
-dBATCH
-dNOPAUSE
-dNOPROMPT
-sDEVICE=tiff24nc
-dUseCIEColor
-dTextAlphaBits=4
-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4
-dEPSCrop
Many thanks,
Pat

Comment: How does it fail? Errors out? Fails to convert? produces garbage? I know older versions of ghostscript could not handle CMYK pdfs.

Comment: Which version of gs on which OS?

Comment: The server is running ghostscript 8.70 on Linux. @ Marc, the PDF doesn't convert at all, i'm trying to get the error output so I can post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some times ghostscript fails in opening files due to XREF table corruption

try to repair problematic pdf with

**pdftk**

- http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/

`pdftk file.pdf output fixed.pdf`

if pdftk is able to repair pdf file, then a shellscript can be made with an

`if...then..else` statement (if pdf file causes ghostscript failing, then it will be automatically repaired by pdftk and then resubmitted to ghostscript)

apart all; you need to learn to **READ ERROR OUTPUT**, since in error output are almost the 99% of times contained the explanations of error

Comment: going to look at this now. i'll also try and get the error output for the failed pdf. thanks

Comment: using PDFTK to fix the xref table seems to have cured the problem and ghostscript will now convert the PDF as expected. thats a great little toolkit for PDF's too. Thanks for sharing.